# AIX: lsdev error on pkcs11 device

Tags: devices, aix

```
lsdev|wc -l
lsdev: 0514-521 Cannot find information in the predefined device
        configuration database for the customized device pkcs11.
      80
```

If I remove with odmdelete the pkcs11 device(or pseudodevice), then at reboot it is re-created and gives me this error again.
I know it is an ssl-related device, but why does it give me this error if the device is in the ODM?

```
 odmget -q name=pkcs11  CuDv

CuDv:
        name = "pkcs11"
        status = 0
        chgstatus = 3
        ddins = "pkcs11"
        location = ""
        parent = ""
        connwhere = ""
        PdDvLn = "adapter/pseudo/pkcs11"
```

Comment: the security.pkcs11 fileset is installed? (`lslpp -l security.pkcs11` says "APPLIED" or "COMMITTED" ?)

Comment: No it wasn't,after installed I resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff Schaller mentions - the cause is probably a missing fileset.

To answer your question - the error message is occurring because `lsdev` is trying - and failing to find anything - with something similar to:

```
odmget -q uniquetype="adapter/pseudo/pkcs11" PdDv
```

If you can get to installp sources I would expect the fileset `security.acf` - as I see 23 `odmadd` stanzas in that fileset:

```
root@x062:[/export/lpp/7103/installp/ppc/xx/usr/lpp/security.acf]grep -c "adapter/pseudo/pkcs11" * | grep -v :0
liblpp.a:27
security.acf.kpkcs11.odmadd:23
security.acf.kpkcs11.odmdel:2
security.acf.kpkcs11.unodmadd:2
```

And, if I wanted to install security.pkcs11 I would have to search further - my `installp` sources only contain an update. (The `:S:` (2nd and 3rd lines) indicates only an update, while `:I:` (1st line) indicates a base install

```
root@x062:[/export/lpp/7103/installp/ppc]installp -d . -L | grep "security\."
security.acf:security.acf:7.1.3.0::I:C:::::b:ACF/PKCS11 Device Driver ::::0:1341:
security.acf:security.acf:7.1.3.45::S:C:::::b:ACF/PKCS11 Device Driver::::0:1524:
security.pkcs11:security.pkcs11:7.1.3.15::S:T:::::N:PKCS11 Libraries::::0:1415:
```